# Rename cyrillic filenames in Windows

Tags: python-2.7

So I have a small script which works great in Linux. However it doesn't for Windows. My googling skill wasn't very helpful today and here I'm.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
name = "Фото"
num = 1

for file in os.listdir("."):    
    if file[-4:].lower() == ".jpg":
        os.rename(file, name + "_" + str(num) + ".jpg")     
        num += 1
```

Actual result: Р¤РѕС‚Рѕ_1.jpg

Expected result: Фото_1.jpg

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by converting files into unicode instead of using str and parse filenames as unicode string further:

```
for file in os.listdir(u'.')
```